# Как сделать скриншот определенного Frame в iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

У меня имеется приложение в определенном Frame рисуется график, я бы хотел сохранить этот график в формате png. Пока вижу способ только, сделать скриншот этого Frame, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как вариант. Можно сохранить UIView в формате png.

Категория UIView. Интерфейс:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIView (Screenshot)

- (UIImage*) takeScreenshot;

@end
```

Имплементация:

```
#import "UIView+Screenshot.h"

@implementation UIView (Screenshot)

- (UIImage*) takeScreenshot
{
    UIImage* image = nil;

    if (CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) > 0 && CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) > 0)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
        [self.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    return image;
}

@end
```

Далее в любом модуле:

```
#import "UIView+Screenshot.h"

...

UIImage* image = [view takeScreenshot];

if (image)
{
    // Create path.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];

    // Save image.
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!